# Filter bright dots from the gradient of the image

Tags: image-processing, image

I am wondering how to filter out bright dots in the picture, which are caused by background noise.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to filter out the "worm" too?

Comment: What about a median filter?

Comment: Does `MinFilter[img, 5]` give something acceptable?

Comment: If you had an image without any interesting dots (like a test picture), you might be able to find the differences between the two images...

Comment: You mean something like `MatrixPlot@ImageData@ColorConvert[image, "GrayScale"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do with ground truth data to assess the result. Is this acceptable as a first step?

```
Manipulate[
    HighlightImage[
         i, 
         result = Binarize[TopHatTransform[i, radius], thr]], 
    {{radius, 4}, 1, 10, 1}, {{thr, .015}, 0, .2}]
```

[image]